# What is common approach for offline fist app with GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I've read a lot about GraphQL and I like it. Especially in conjunction with Relay and React-Native. But while thinking about whole app architecture I can't fill one gap. In order to make reliable app in should work well if there is no internet connection. So common scenario is to write REST responses to DB and reflect these data to UI. But in case GraphQL idea is that data might be incomplete.

So what is the best/common approach to store data that come from GraphQL backend in order to be offline available ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching the same :P
With Apollo you can get an offline graphql approach, but is not offline first. I think this does not exist at the moment :(

Another alternative is Realm with MongoDB:
"MongoDB Realm will combine Realm, the popular mobile database and data synchronization technology, and MongoDB Stitch, the serverless platform for MongoDB, into a unified solution that makes it easy for you to build powerful and engaging experiences on more devices." - August 2020

Comment: you are right. despite 3 years passed I did not hear about any improvements regarding offline first mode.

Another solution worth mentioning is couchbase db. But all these solutions brig some restrictions to the whole project. It requires the back-end to run on a particular service. Usually, I do not have a chance to change thch-stack on back-end. So I've been looking for some solution for mobile-only which do not care about server architecture but communication protocol only.

Comment: Yesterday I started coding a simple solution for this ... basically it works with two classes in javascript ... one for the local database and another for the online database ...
So, you can configure these classes with the classic CRUD functions, and the code has the logic to mix the data correctly in offline or online mode ...
I will share the code with you when I finish it.